# How do you change the size of an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams

I have setup my ImageView like the following:

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/dl_image"
               android:layout_width="60dp"
               android:background="@drawable/pictureframe"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Notice that layout_width is fixed to 60dp.  Depending on the content that I acquired online, I want to resize this width to 90dp, or 120dp (while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image).

I tried using setLayoutParams, but passing LayoutParams(120, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) throws an exception. It doesn't seem to like it.

If possible, I am trying to avoid making another ImageView for larger sizes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're working with an existing view it can be a lot of work creating a new set of `LayoutParams` from scratch. Instead - you can grab the view's existing LayoutParams, edit these, and then apply them to the view to update its LayoutParams using `setLayoutParams()`

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 120;
// existing height is ok as is, no need to edit it
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Make sure you import the correct type of `LayoutParams`. For this case, as you commented, you can just use the `LayoutParams` of a `ViewGroup`. If you were setting parameters specific to a certain type of view (e.g. alignments in `RelativeLayout`s) you would have to import the `LayoutParams` of that type of view.

Comment: It looks like it works this way. I used ViewGroup's LayoutParams. It seems to work just fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: @alnite - Glad to have helped. Thanks for letting me know about `ViewGroup`, edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: It seems that you don't even need to re-set the `layoutParams` to the view. It works simply by changing their values.

Answer (score 9):

you can do it all like

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
```