# Change ImageView size on WindowManager programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

I have an ImageView service that added to the WindowManger here is the code

```
    android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutparams = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0x40028, -3);
    layoutparams.gravity = 17;
    layoutparams.x = 0;
    layoutparams.y = 0;

    windowManager.addView(targetIcon, layoutparams);
```

I want to decrease it size a little bit from the user via Seekbar,

tried everything  to change the size after adding the image to screen

I've tried this but the image disapear

```
 android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutparams = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(targetIcon.getWidth()-15, targetIcon.getHeight()-15, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0x40028, -3);
```

also I've tried this but nothing happened

```
 targetIcon.getLayoutParams().width = targetIcon.getWidth()-100;
        targetIcon.getLayoutParams().height = targetIcon.getHeight()-100;
```

all I want to do is to decrease it size (width,height) between 1 dp to 10 dp

**Explanation**  when the image is 45dp and the user change the seekbar one step it decreased the image to 44dp and the max seekbar is 10 so it will be 35dp

Answer (score 0):

Hey there use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453004/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-an-imageview?rq=1) .
definitely u will get your answer..

Comment: `layoutparams.height = 35;
        layoutparams.width = 35;
        windowManager.addView(targetIcon, layoutparams);`  this code works but the size is so small because it is in pixel how can I get the image width and height and decrease it size like getWidth-10  ,, when I call the getWidth and getHeight they return 0 why